# When does $HOD^{V[G]} \subseteq V$?

Tags: lo.logic, set-theory, forcing

Assume that $\mathbb{P}\in HOD$ is non-trivial. It is well-known that if $\mathbb{P}$
satisfies some homogeneity properties, then $HOD^{V[G]} \subseteq V$, where $G$ is $\mathbb{P}$-generic over $V$.

> **Question.** Is there a necessary and sufficient condition on $\mathbb{P}$ implying 
>   $HOD^{V[G]} \subseteq V$, whenever $G$ is $\mathbb{P}$-generic over $V$?

Comment: are there any references for this Q, I've looked and like there's **2** papers, both by the same bloke?

Comment: can i answer 'no'

Comment: @JonMarkPerry Sorry, but I do not understand what you say.

Comment: you could say that to any answer!

Comment: but some questions are independence, so you can not say a yes or no answer to them

Comment: so 'maybe, maybe not'?